# Use Google's mobile vision api to detect numbers only?

Tags: android-vision

I would like to know how I can filter to detect numbers (integers) only? e.g 1,2,....,10. Currently the api detects all formats of "text".

Answer (score 0):

You should do that processing on your side. Use Regex to filter out numbers from string received from Vision API:

```
str="Text received 123,0";
number = str.replace(/\D/g,'');

result: 123
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

> Google vision API will detect all character, google vision does not
>   have separate API(which can detect only number at the point of
>   scanning) for only numbers till now, But after scanning the image
>   using google vision api we will get the text in response example
>   "23XA3783", so now we can replace the character we don't want.
>
> Store the google api response in temp variable

source_str = "23XA3783"

> In my case I get the required string from google api response using
>   js

source_str= temp["responses"][0].textAnnotations[0].description

```
  final_output = source_str.replace(/\D/g,'');
```